# Overwrite CSS: .container > *

Tags: css

I'm trying to overwrite a line-height that has been set up in a theme using:

```
.container > *{font:normal 22px/28px sans-serif;}
```

The div I am targeting is well nested inside of .container but everything I try doesn't work!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put some code example in jsFiddle

Comment: Try `.container > *{font:normal 22px/28px sans-serif !important;}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you read the question properly. I'm trying to overwrite that style's line-height with another one. !important doesn't work either.

Comment: You should show at least something that you actually tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the div you want to style has class called myClass, then do this:

```
.container .myClass
{
  line-height: x px; /* whatever you need */
}
```

This will override the  original selector because it is more specific

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3vS8y/2/)**

Comment: But now you need to add an extra class in the HTML. That wasn't the question because he now doesn't override anything, just adding an extra class!

Comment: @Timo002, 1) the OP says: "The div I am targeting" - so I think he already has a class/id there. 2) Yes this *does* override the line-height which was set to all child elements of the container

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you understood what I was trying to get at. Your demo is good proof so I'm accepting this answer, even though it still isn't working for me - I think this has something to do with stylesheet loading order as mentioned above...

Answer (score -2):

Probably it has something to do with the order the CSS is loaded. Load you CSS after the theme CSS is loaded. If that still doesn't work use the `!important` at the end of your own CSS!

Like this:

```
.container > *{
  font:normal 22px/28px sans-serif!important;
}
```

Comment: !important was the first thing I tried! Didn't work... Yeah it seems the themes sheet is loaded after mine. But using !important, then that shouldn't matter no?

Comment: It matters, if it has important too.

Comment: It doesn't have !important, so I don't get why I can't get to it.

Comment: @lorenzium, what do you mean with "It doesn't have !important"? Can you use developer tools to see what style is overruling yourse? Maybe add some code or link to the project if it is online available.